# Writing objects to file with private fields and private constructor

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, constructor, private

I'm trying to write objects of type User from an arraylist to a file- preferably CSV, but it's not that important as long as I can read the objects back in from the file and store them in an arraylist (to use for getting further information on the objects).

My problem is that not only are all the fields private, but so is the only constructor. It's a third party class (User.class) which doesn't implement Serializable.

I've tried so many different ways to do this, but the problem always arises from the constructor. User.class doesn't have a default constructor. The error I keep seeing is 'constructor is not visible'.

I have tried using reflection to access the constructor and fields, but I can't seem to get it all linking up properly.

Basically, in what way would you approach this problem? Should I keep working on reflection? I just seem to be going round in circles here!

Comment: If the object has a private constructor there must be a factory method for it somewhere.

Comment: I'm assuming that's the part at the end of the class: 'private static class UserFactory implements ItemFactory<User>{method}'? I will figure out what to do with this new information, thank you!

Comment: Because the factory method is also private, I'm getting the same kind of error but with the factory method instead of the constructor

Comment: There must be a *public* factory method for it somewhere. Otherwise nobody could use it at all. Or else a protected factory method, or package-private. If either of those, you're out of luck.

Comment: There isn't- only: 'private static class UserFactory
    implements ItemFactory<User>
  {
    public User createItemFromElement(DomElement element)
    {method}' - Could I still work with reflection and accessing the private constructor?

Comment: There must be something more public that returns you a factory. Note that the factory method itself is public, and presumably `ItemFactory` and `User` are as well.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, and the one I would use, is the following:

- Create a Serializable class that is User factory, called say UserFactory
- Give it a field for each Serializable User field you want to persist
- Define a method that accepts a User and saves the values to its own fields. You may have to go deeper to get to Serializable values
- Define a factory method that uses the fields to create a User via the factory method in User

Such an object would be Serializable and you would need only to do the extra steps of putting the User object in before writing, and getting the User object out after reading.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input- it's funny, I started off doing something similar to this. Just needed more patience and the reassurance that it will actually work!